# Spotify play/pause controlling from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, remote, cmd.exe, spotify

How can I control Spotify using command line in windows xp? I know how to do it in dbus on linux, but I have no idea how to do it in windows. You can show me universal command for stopping any music player. Thanks a lot

Comment: Music players are not so standardised that there is one command that will stop all of them. The closest you can get is the mute button.

Answer (score 3):

This might help :
[Spotify command line](https://code.google.com/p/spotifycmd/)

Comment: Works on Windows, but only for playpause/next/forward.

The volume and status controls do not work.  :(

Comment: Compiles but fails to attach to spotify; ERROR  Can not find spotify, is it running?